# Registration for own site viat twitter

Tags: twitter

anyone knows if it is possible to do registration via twitter just like facebook register (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)?

it is not login via twitter. i need to store some basic information from the twitter user, eg, name and email, and then request user to choose their own username and password for my site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't have this functionality at all , they have [@anywhere](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome) for integration for some Twitter features on your website. That's the closest there is to this. What you can do is register an account with the information you gather from an authenticating user, but the development of this would be up to you. There are no boxed up solutions right now from Twitter. There may be something third party but I'm not aware of any.

It's also "against the rules"

> You may not use Twitter Content or other data collected from end users
>   of your Client to create or maintain a separate status update or
>   social network database or service.

---

https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms